# Valid regular expression not correctly matching in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm trying to capture every name inside the single quotes in this list: http://pastie.org/private/lnuqeqkxenncbyjp81bew

For example, the first few matches would be: `(Dba)` `(Uk)` `Co.,Inc.`
From `(2, '(Dba)'), (2, '(Uk)'), (2, 'Co.,Inc.'),`

I believe this regex should correctly match everything `.*\'(.*)\'\),`

When I try this in Sublime Text 2, I get no matches.  If I try it using https://regex101.com/#pcre, I get a match only on the first line, but not on every line.  If I try on http://regexpal.com/, I get a match on every line (which I expect).

I'm not sure what flavor of regex Sublime Text 2 uses or how I should change my regex to get it to find every match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following fix:

```
.*'\K(.*)(?='\)(?:,|$))
```

You just need not escape the single apostrophes, and I added `\K` to omit the beginning of the match and the lookahead to exclude the ending. The `(?:,|$)` is to make sure the last entry is matched.

[image]

Or just use yours if you plan to replace with `$1`:

```
.*'(.*)'\)(?:,|$)
```

[image]

Well, talking about optimizing the regex, you can use negated character class here:

```
.*'([^']*)'\)(?:,|$)
```

Or

```
.*'\K([^']*)(?='\)(?:,|$))
```

These ones are faster.